# Kestrel returns empty response to HttpContext

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have set up a basic Kestrel instance in a Console Application like so:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace HiStackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:5001")
                .Configure(c =>
                    c.Run(a =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("writing response");
                            return a.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world");
                        }
                    )
                )
                .Build();
            
            host.Start();
            
            Console.WriteLine("Host setup finished, continuing with program.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If I then navigate to `http://localhost:5001/` in a web browser, the application runs the code to send a response (breakpoints are hit, and "writing response" is written to the console), however, I receive an empty response. Specifically ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in Chrome.

If I try to view the response in Postman I receive a "Socket hang up" error.

I cannot figure out why this is happening. This is the first time I'm attempting to set up a Kestrel instance from scratch, so if anybody could shed some light on the problem it would be a huge help. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is a Server.  When you use a browser to connect you are sending a Request to your Server.  The Server then sends a response back to the browser which is a html message.  You are sending text back to the browser.

Comment: @jdweng I was under the impression ‘a‘ in this case was the HttpContext formed as part of the incoming request from my browser?

Comment: Send an html string like code in following : https://www.learn-html.org/en/Hello%2C_World%21

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I still receive an empty response. I don't think it's the formatting of the response as you are able to send more than just HTML. I have also tried this in Postman, where I receive the following error: Socket hang up.

Comment: Are you getting a response? There should be a status like 200 OK or 400/500 error.  If you are not getting any response you may need a secure connection HTTPS.  See : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22563

Comment: Yup, no response at all. There is no HTTP code coming back, literally 0 bytes. Thanks, I'll check that out now.

Comment: according to this documentation, this is how to set up server for web server implementation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `UseStartup<Startup>()`, but you didn't post the `Startup` class code. If I remove that from your example it works fine.

Additionaly you're calling `HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync()` which returns a Task (it's asynchronous).
You should await it like this:

```
.Configure(c =>
    c.Run(async a =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("writing response");
            await a.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world");
        }
    )
)
```

Comment: Fantastic, this has fixed my issue. Thank you! I'm not sure why the inclusion of Startup would affect it? I'll have a look into it.

Comment: It depends on your startup code. You might be short-circuiting the request processing pipeline or something...